# Symbolicate crash log not working

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, debug-symbols

I have an ad_hoc app distribuited with enterprise profile, i have collected a crash from one of the users, he copy and past the crash log directly from the Iphone settings. This is the log i have received:

```
 {"app_name":"myapp","timestamp":"2017-05-24 11:05:39.40 -0500","app_version":"1.2","slice_uuid":"307b6064-504c-31a7-ad90-838841735148","adam_id":0,"build_version":"1.2","bundleID":"com.myappofficialdev.myappofficialdev","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 10.3.1 (14E304)","incident_id":"839AD0C6-14B1-40E8-ACB9-27B31E82DD11","name":"myapp"}

Incident Identifier: 839AD0C6-14B1-40E8-ACB9-27B31E82DD11

CrashReporter Key:   2fe43d99bbf03fe054d0d80fb25ff2161fd0505a

Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2

Process:             myapp [713]

Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0508EF38-8A96-4D67-BE19-247F7110B88F/myapp.app/myapp

Identifier:          com.myappofficialdev.myappofficialdev

Version:             1.2 (1.2)

Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)

Role:                Foreground

Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Coalition:           com.myappofficialdev.myappofficialdev [466]



Date/Time:           2017-05-24 11:05:38.9319 -0500

Launch Time:         2017-05-24 10:59:29.4060 -0500

OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.1 (14E304)

Report Version:      104


Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Triggered by Thread:  0


Application Specific Information:

abort() called


Filtered syslog:

None found


Last Exception Backtrace:

(0x18f542fd8 0x18dfa4538 0x18f426518 0x19c714980 0x19c71464c 0x1a54e190c 0x1a54e1218 0x1956a70ec 0x1956a706c 0x1956915e0 0x1956a6950 0x1956a646c 0x1956a1804 0x195672418 0x195e6bf64 0x195e666c0 0x195e66aec 0x18f4f1424 0x18f4f0d94 0x18f4ee9a0 0x18f41ed94 0x190e88074 0x1956d7130 0x100034050 0x18e42d59c)


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib       
0x000000018e53d014 0x18e51e000 + 126996

1   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
0x000000018e607334 0x18e602000 + 21300

2   libsystem_c.dylib            
0x000000018e4b19c4 0x18e450000 + 399812

3   libc++abi.dylib              
0x000000018df7d1b0 0x18df7c000 + 4528

4   libc++abi.dylib              
0x000000018df96c04 0x18df7c000 + 109572

5   libobjc.A.dylib              
0x000000018dfa4820 0x18df9c000 + 34848

6   libc++abi.dylib              
0x000000018df935d4 0x18df7c000 + 95700

7   libc++abi.dylib              
0x000000018df931a8 0x18df7c000 + 94632

8   libobjc.A.dylib              
0x000000018dfa46f8 0x18df9c000 + 34552

9   CoreFoundation               
0x000000018f41ee00 0x18f416000 + 36352

10  GraphicsServices             
0x0000000190e88074 0x190e7c000 + 49268

11  UIKit                        
0x00000001956d7130 0x195662000 + 479536

12  myapp                    
0x0000000100034050 0x10000c000 + 163920

13  libdyld.dylib                
0x000000018e42d59c 0x18e429000 + 17820


Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread

Thread 1:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib       
0x000000018e51f224 0x18e51e000 + 4644

1   libsystem_kernel.dylib       
0x000000018e51f09c 0x18e51e000 + 4252

2   CoreFoundation               
0x000000018f4f0e88 0x18f416000 + 896648

3   CoreFoundation               
0x000000018f4eeadc 0x18f416000 + 887516

4   CoreFoundation               
0x000000018f41ed94 0x18f416000 + 36244

5   Foundation                   
0x000000018ff38d64 0x18ff2c000 + 52580

6   Foundation                   
0x000000018ff59b34 0x18ff2c000 + 187188

7   UIKit                        
0x00000001960615f8 0x195662000 + 10483192

8   Foundation                   
0x00000001900362c8 0x18ff2c000 + 1090248

9   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
0x000000018e60575c 0x18e602000 + 14172

10  libsystem_pthread.dylib      
0x000000018e60566c 0x18e602000 + 13932

11  libsystem_pthread.dylib      
0x000000018e602d84 0x18e602000 + 3460


Thread 2 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader

Thread 2:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib       
0x000000018e51f224 0x18e51e000 + 4644

1   libsystem_kernel.dylib       
0x000000018e51f09c 0x18e51e000 + 4252

2   CoreFoundation               
0x000000018f4f0e88 0x18f416000 + 896648

3   CoreFoundation               
0x000000018f4eeadc 0x18f416000 + 887516

4   CoreFoundation               
0x000000018f41ed94 0x18f416000 + 36244

5   CFNetwork                    
0x000000018fc2aca4 0x18fb49000 + 924836

6   Foundation                   
0x00000001900362c8 0x18ff2c000 + 1090248

7   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
0x000000018e60575c 0x18e602000 + 14172

8   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
0x000000018e60566c 0x18e602000 + 13932

9   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
0x000000018e602d84 0x18e602000 + 3460


Thread 3:

0   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
0x000000018e602d78 0x18e602000 + 3448


Thread 4:

0   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
0x000000018e602d78 0x18e602000 + 3448


Thread 5:

0   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
0x000000018e602d78 0x18e602000 + 3448


Thread 6:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib       
0x000000018e53da88 0x18e51e000 + 129672

1   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
0x000000018e6030a0 0x18e602000 + 4256

2   libsystem_pthread.dylib      
0x000000018e602d7c 0x18e602000 + 3452


Thread 7:


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):

    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001702e6737

    x4: 0x000000018df97b07   x5: 0x000000016fdf3560   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec

    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x000000000000000b  x11: 0x000000000000000b

   x12: 0x0000000000000010  x13: 0x000000018f78dc0e  x14: 0x0000030000000300  x15: 0x0000000000000000

   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006

   x20: 0x00000001b57f4b40  x21: 0x000000016fdf3560  x22: 0x00000001b57fbbb8  x23: 0x0000000000000001

   x24: 0x0000000170018510  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000001  x27: 0x0000000000000000

   x28: 0x000000016fdf3bc0   fp: 0x000000016fdf34c0   lr: 0x000000018e607334

    sp: 0x000000016fdf34a0   pc: 0x000000018e53d014 cpsr: 0x00000000


Binary Images:

0x10000c000 - 0x10004ffff myapp arm64  <307b6064504c31a7ad90838841735148> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/0508EF38-8A96-4D67-BE19-247F7110B88F/myapp.app/myapp
```

[here the complete crash log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8YbvU5nFzWcem1kU0pwa2w0RU0)

I'm trying to symbolicate this log to investigate the resons of the crash. I have tried the classic procedure inside Xcode:

- Open Devices menu
- Drag and drop the .crash file
- eventually click Re-symbolicate log

This method not works for me, the log remains unsymbolicated.

So i have tried another method

[This method](https://medium.com/@Mrugraj/crash-re-symbolication-5c28d3a3a883)

The resulting log in terminal is unsymbolicated. 
I can find myxarchive, my .app file and my .dSYM.
What i can do to investigate this log? Or maybe there is a another way to have more detail? I have excluded atos, because it takes too much time i think...

EDIT

i'm trying atos also, i can't symbolicate , this is a piece of terminal result that maybe can suggest something to more expert eyes:

```
Imac:MYAPP user$ atos -arch arm64  -o 'MYAPP.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MYAPP' 0x000000018e51f09c 0x18e51e000
0x000000018e51f09c
0x18e51e000
```

This not return any error but the symbolication not works

Comment: ok.. do you have DSYM file? If Yes, the please look at the accepted answer  in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports

Also look into these links https://www.plausible.coop/blog/?p=176
http://noverse.com/blog/2010/03/how-to-deal-with-an-iphone-crash-report/